# Is possible Identify accessed page before page 404?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, htaccess, 404-page, 404

I have a new Magento store (version 1.9.3.1), I have already checked all the links and all are working normally, however in Google Analytics there are many hits that are causing the 404 error, I wonder if there is any way to identify where these hits are coming from , If the Magento has some functionality for this...

See Google Analytics, the `/pagina-nao-encontrada` is page 404 that have 103 hits:
[image]

The important thing is where the error is coming from, if I succeed in some way, by session, by cookie, by htaccess, and then I could send to PHP page as a post and send an email myself, but that part I know How to do it, I just do not know how to identify where the error is coming from.